# Build ROS from source without using default ffmpeg in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all:

My environment:

1. OS: Ubuntu 12.10 OpenCV: 2.4.5 release
2. PCL: 1.6.0 release (built from source)
3. ffmpeg: 1.2 release (built from source)
4. VTK: 5.10.1 release (built from source)
5. boost: 1.50.0 (installed from the repository)

There are some reasons that I really don't want to use the default:

1. ffmpeg -- libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev
2. VTK 5.8.0 boost 1.49

from the default repository.

Now here comes my question:

I did have my ffmpeg 1.2 installed [http://visionopen.com/questions/ffmpeg.png http://visionopen.com/questions/ffmpeg.png](http://visionopen.com/questions/ffmpeg.png)
and vtk 5.10.1 installed [http://visionopen.com/questions/vtk.png http://visionopen.com/questions/vtk.png](http://visionopen.com/questions/vtk.png)

but, when I tried to install ROS from source (refer to http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source),
the following command

```
:~/ros_catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
still requires the following packages:
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libvtk5-dev libvtk5.8
```

I'm thinking at least, there is something like in CMake which lets me to select my own path/directory, rather than setup by ROS itself. There should be existing such a freedom to let me specify which version and which directory of ffmpeg, which version and which directory of vtk.
But, according to http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source, I can't find such a freedom. Can anybody help to let me know how to build ROS from source based on the dependencies that I myself am able to specify?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards

Pei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63615/build-ros-from-source-without-using-default-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [jiapei100](https://answers.ros.org/users/1310/jiapei100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-29**:
Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you, I was out of internet coverage for a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that step you are using `rosdep` to resolve dependencies for the packages which are in your src directory. One or more of those packages indirectly depend on:

```
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libvtk5-dev libvtk5.8
```

All `rosdep` does it look at the declared dependencies, which are declared using rosdep keys, like `vtk` and translates them to one or more OS installer key(s). In the case of `vtk` that is `libvtk5-dev` for `apt`. See:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L1089

I can only guess that this `apt` package depends directly on `libvtk5.8`. This is probably a similar problem to why `libav*` packages are getting pulled in.

You do not *have* to resolve all of the dependencies from `rosdep`, it is simply a tool to help with that. If you know you have `ffmpeg` from source then you can just ignore `rosdep` and not install it. The from source build of ROS will continue and find your version of `ffmpeg` if it is on the appropriate `PATH`'s.

You can use this command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy --simulate
```

to see what `rosdep` *would* do and you can cherry pick out the `apt-get` calls which you want and run them manually. After that you can continue with the source installation normally.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-29**:
The `rosdep check` option is also helpful in this situation.